# Google cloud composer-airflow throws error: Broken DAG: File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/_pandas_helpers.py

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-composer, airflow-2.x

I am trying to created a DAG in Cloud Composer. When importing, I'm getting the following error:

```
Broken DAG: [/home/airflow/gcs/dags/branch_name/persoflow/dags/test_dag.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/_pandas_helpers.py", line 628, in download_arrow_row_iterator
    yield _row_iterator_page_to_arrow(page, column_names, arrow_types)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/_pandas_helpers.py", line 601, in _row_iterator_page_to_arrow
    arrays.append(pyarrow.array(page._columns[column_index], type=arrow_type))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'array'
```

Version used :

`composer-1.17.9-airflow-2.1.4`

To dig deeper I checked the python file  [pandas_helpers.py](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/0384238268a9cc84275eb5350458a91ec81e1d68/bigquery/google/cloud/bigquery/_pandas_helpers.py#L628).

In the code we are using bigquery client to get the bigquery query result to dataframe like this

```
client = bigquery.Client(project=bq_project) 
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()
client.query(query, job_config=job_config).to_dataframe(['list1'].values.tolist()[0]
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Can you replace the third line of the code that you have provided with these two lines in your code and check the results? 
`df=client.query(query,job_config=job_config).to_dataframe()
  print(df['list1'].tolist())`

Comment: Did the above comment help you in resolving the issue?

Comment: Not yet tried. Will update once its done

Comment: @PrajnaRaiT Sorry for the delay in response but the solution did not work and we moved ahead by installing the older version of bigquery on composer environment

Comment: Is your issue resolved by installing the older version of Bigquery on Composer environment?

Comment: Yes , the same code working with older stable version of bigquery

Comment: As the issue has resolved, can you add the resolution steps as an answer to this question?